# Attribute error when using tensorflow with elu

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.5

When trying to use the tensorflow library I got an attribute error output

**TF version:**

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\vinhalivinhali\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorboard, wrapt, keras-preprocessing, protobuf, wheel, numpy, gast, tensorflow-estimator, termcolor, google-pasta, grpcio, absl-py, keras-applications, astor, opt-einsum, six
Required-by:
```

**Python version**

```
Python 3.5.0
```

**IMPORTS**

```
import tensorflow as tf # for Deep Learning
import pandas as pd # for data manipulation
import numpy as np # for matrix manipulation
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # for graphics
```

**SCRIPT**

```
X0 = X[:, 0, :] # get the data in the first time period
Ht = tf.elu(tf.matmul(X0, Wx_h) + b) # uses X0 to initiate the hidden state
y = [] # list to be populated with outputs every time period
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnrs.py", line 40, in <module>
    Ht = tf.elu(tf.matmul(X0, Wx_h) + b) # uses X0 to initiate the hidden state
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'elu'
```

Comment: try `tf.nn.elu` instead

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnrs.py", line 40, in <module>
    Ht = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(X0, Wx_h) + b)
NameError: name 'Wx_h' is not defined

Comment: There was the following exit @MihailBurduja

Comment: You didn't define `Wx_h`. You should declare it as `Wx_h = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal((200, X0.shape[0])))` and the `b` variable as well. I suggest you consider TF Keras, as it's much simpler and higher level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `elu` function is in the `tf.nn` module, see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/elu).

Comment: I tested but got the output below:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "rnrs.py", line 40, in <module> Ht = tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(X0, Wx_h) + b) NameError: name 'Wx_h' is not defined